# Get Information from one page to another with angular routing

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, url, routes

Image a page, that page is called "dashboard". In the dashboard, there is a drop-down menu, with items, which are listed by the PHP script, and their count varies on the number of results from a database.

[image: State 1 - Dashboard with opened drop-down menu]

Now, when a user clicks one of the items from the menu, it should redirect him to the configuration page, with some data (id, type). Sounds simple, but the redirecting method used is made with angular, so it uses URL hashing, without refreshing the site. URL of configuration page then looks like:

> https://www.example.com/index.php#/configure

...and I want to get there some data. The site we see there is just a blank site, which, in the file tree, is named "configuration.php", but you don't see it in the URL, because of angular code in "configure.module.js.php", which simply redirects the user, gives them the right site with:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('BlurAdmin.pages.configure', [])
      .config(routeConfig);

  /** @ngInject */
  function routeConfig($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('configure', {
          url: '/configure',
          title: 'Configuration',
          templateUrl: 'app/pages/configure/configure.php',
          controller: 'addCtrl',
        });
  }

})();
```

So I assume, that if I want to get the data to my site, I need some kind of a GET request. I figured out, that it will work if I use the GET request like so:

```
https://www.example.com/index.php?something=works&omg=itWorks#/configure
```

So my index.php will work with the GET data and write them to a SESSION, which can then be used in configuration.php!

Well, it works, kinda... But the main thing is, that it is all angular, so **NO SITE REFRESH AT ALL!** That means none of my files will be refreshed, so after I click the button again, the site will not get the GET request again, it will simply redirect me to configuration.php, without dealing with the new data... It will keep the first GET parameters and SESSION.

So there goes my question. how to make it? I really need that one click to send that data to configuration.php, without refreshing the site, but, working and updating.

Comment: use some tutorials https://www.sitepoint.com/write-modular-code-angular-ui-router-named-views/

Comment: Angular is a client side "framework" it's meant to use Ajax to request data from the server and load it into an HTML template. If you are trying to both pass data to a php file and use Angular to render it, Angular routing isn't for you. You should pass an HTML template to Angular and have an Ajax request to the server for any necessary data. Or redirect to a new PHP page without using Angular's routing.

Comment: One does not "get data to a site". One uses `$http.get` to **get data *from* a site** and `$http.post` to **post data *to* a site**. For more information see [MDN Web Techology Reference - HTTP request methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods).

Answer (score 1):

In html you add ui-sref to like this

```
ui-sref="configure/({id: valueid})
```

in file config

```
url:'/configure/:id'
```

in your controller add $stateParams like this

```
 function addCtrl($scope,$http,$stateParams)
```

and use ajax to GET

```
   var params = $.param({'id':$stateParams.id})

        $http({
                    method:'GET',
                    url:'yoururl?id=' + $stateParams.id,
                    data:params,
                    headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }

                }).then(onSuccess);
```